# How to measure the perfomance of the jQuery code

Tags: jquery, benchmarking

I know some selectors are faster than others, and of course our own methods can be faster or slower.

Is there any software/app that analyzes cpu usage or even is able to compare/benchmark among versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heck yeah!

> ### [js*Perf* — JavaScript performance playground](http://jsperf.com)
>
> #### What is jsPerf?
>
> jsPerf aims to provide an easy way to create and share test cases,
> comparing the performance of different JavaScript snippets by running
> benchmarks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/), which, given the appropriate html to work with, and a range of JavaScript approaches/'Test cases', will give a performance analysis of those approaches.